# Set label of $entity programmatically in a custom form

Tags: 8, forms

I need to change the label of a custom content type programmatically. I've looked around but I couldn't find a solution. This is my custom form:

```
class GroupContentForm extends ContentEntityForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $entity = $this->entity;

    $entity->set('label', 'kkkkk');
    $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);

    $form_state->setRedirect('entity.group_content.canonical', ['group_content' => $entity->id()]);
  }

}
```

What do I need to do to change the label? `$entity->set('label', 'kkkkk');` causes an error as the field label doesn't exists, the same happens with `title` and `_title`

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what entity type you have. In the question you ask for the label of a content type, which would be the entity `node`, then the label field is `title`. In the question title it is a more general question about the label of an entity and in the code you redirect to a `group_content` entity route, which would suggest this is another entity type.

In this case, if you don't know the entity type, you could use this generic code to get the label field name and set the label with it:

```
$label_field = $entity->getEntityType()->getKey('label');
$entity->set($label_field, 'New label');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update a node you can use [`setTitle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AsetTitle/8.3.x), like this:

```
$entity->setTitle('My custom title');
```

For other entity types you can use:

```
$entity->setLabel('My custom title');
```

I also see that you don't save the entity, make sure to save the entity after setting the title:

```
$entity->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `hook_entity_presave`?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
  if ($type == 'node') {
    // Add more logic based on your needs.
    $entity->set('title', 'kkkkk');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that set the titles for all nodes, I only need it in my custom form.

Comment: Yes, you need to define the specific content type in code. If you want to just alter the form label and not to alter the title of actual entity, them `hook_form_alter()` might be better way.